# Mosfet Damage (ESD?)

Tags: mosfet, esd

I have a few p-channel mosfets (IRLML6401) on PCB's, and it seems like the resistance between the gate and the source varies from 600 to 1100ohms. Obviously this resistance should be in the megaohms range, so I was wondering what could be causing this. They function otherwise, could it be a breakdown in the oxide barrier from ESD? The boards were assembled in china, so it's possible that this factory (we've had QC issues with other stuff) might not be using proper protection?

Comment: Explain **how** you measured this resistance because I can come up with 10 ways to "measure" that, most of which will actually measure something else entirely.

Comment: Measured in circuit, and then desoldered and measured out of circuit, both with a multimeter.

Comment: Maybe the design is flawed but who can tell?

Comment: If the out-of-circuit test with a multimeter gives the same resistance value for both polarities (swapping the leads) then indeed the MOSFET is broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you measured in-circuit, chances are you measured something else. Gates must never be exposed externally  as a high impedance and often the driver RdsOn is only 10 to 100x RdsOn of output stage depending on desired risetime and current levels for high power PWM switches.

For ESD protection, read this.
[image]